# Probability of number of tosses

Tags: probability

A fair dice is tossed until a six is obtained . let $x$ denote the number of tosses required  . What is the probability when $x$ is greater than or equal to 3 .

## My try

when $x=3$

probability $=(5/6)(5/6)(1/6)$

but how to solve that .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula $\frac{5}{6}\cdot \frac{5}{6} \cdot \frac{1}{6}$ is for the six to appear on *exactly* the third throw, i.e. $P(x=3)$.

You need to calculate the probability of it appearing on the third throw *or later*, i.e. $P(x \ge 3)$, which is simply $\frac{5}{6}\cdot \frac{5}{6}$

Answer (score 3):

If $X \geq 3$, it is equivalent to that the first two tosses are not $6$. Therefore, the probability is
$$
\frac{5}{6} \cdot \frac{5}{6}
$$